# Python List being accesed using For Loop causes ValueError

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to access a list within a list using for loop but it gives Value Error

```
for image,text in (images,len(stringer)):
    extract_text(image, stringer[text], "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\MNF\\Image_Text_Extrracted_Images\\")
```

Stringer Contains List Like This
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXmlB.png)

while error looks like these:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B8f0.png)

Comment: maybe try `for image,text in (images, range(len(stringer))):`

Comment: nope didn't work

Comment: How about `for (image, text) in (images, stringer):`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for image,text in zip(images,len(stringer)):
```

This Works Fine I just Forgot To use Zip